# Deliver Pipeline Plugin and its `columns` property does not work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

What is the purpose of the `columns(int number)` of [Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin)? According Job DSL Plugin and its [view reference](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/View-Reference.md) document it specifies the number of columns. I have tried changing this setting to different values and I do not see its effect.

My Delivery pipeline has 3 stages with 3-4 jobs each. What should I expect?

[image]

**EDIT** Open issue [JENKINS-29324](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29324])

```
Jenkins                   v1.619
Delipery Pipeline Plugin  v0.9.4
Build Pipeline Plugin     v1.4.7
```

Answer (score 0):

The `columns(int number)` method configures the "Number of Columns" option of the Delivery Pipeline View settings.

[image]

But changing the value does not seem to have any effect. You should consider to report an issue for the Delivery Pipeline plugin in the [Jenkins Issue Tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS/component/18134).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion: [JENKINS-29324](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29324)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is if you have multiple components defined in the view, then they can be shown in the number of columns that you configure. Will not have any effect if you only have one component defined.